# "Green-eyed monster" before Shakespeare

Tags: idioms

I've been looking for the origins of green as the colour of envy.

So far all I can get is "green-eyed monster" from Othello and vague, hand-wavey remarks about ancient Green ideas about bile.

The Othello line strikes me as being a bit too specific (in "green-eyed") to be an entirely original thought. If green *skin* had been the prevailing association until then, then why not "green-skinned monster"?

To put it another way, could Shakespeare have expected his audience to connect green *eyes* with envy? The green of eyes is far more *literal* than the "green" of skin, which is more grey/pallid.

I suspect there's something in between, perhaps a myth or fable which isn't ranked highly in Google results.

Anyone know what it might be?

Answer (score 1):

OED mentions envy in passing under **green** and intriguingly it introduces yellow:

> **3.** Of the complexion: having a pale, sickly, or bilious hue, indicative of fear, envy, ill humour, or sickness (also in green and wan, green and pale). Also in extended use. See also **green sickness** *n.*
>
> - With reference to envy, chiefly in *green with envy* (also *jealousy*), *green eye n.*  (yellow being the traditional colour of jealousy).

OED gives earliest citations, and *Merchant of Venice* and its "shuddering fear" appeared before *Othello*, but nothing before them:

> **2.** *fig.* In and after Shakespeare.
> **a.** Describing and alluding to jealousy. Cf. **green** *adj. 3.*
>
> > 1600   Shakespeare *Merchant of Venice* III. ii. 110   Shyddring feare, and greene-eyed ielousie.
>
> **b.**   **green-eyed monster** *n.* (usu. with *the*) jealousy.
>
> > a1616   Shakespeare Othello (1622) III. iii. 170   O beware ielousie. It is the greene eyd monster.

*Green with envy* is a lot later:

> 1863   C. Reade *Hard Cash* xliii,   The doctor was turning almost green with jealousy.